# Error when i deploy war file into tomacat 8 manager

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8

I have just finished developing a web app with java(spring and tomcat) and it works well,i exported the war, and when i'm trying to deploy it into tomcat8 manager, it gives me an error
[image]

Comment: can anybody help please!!! PS: the linke above is the error

Comment: How you deploy your app? using the Manager Interface?

Comment: yes i use the interface

Comment: @estem please provide more info, like Tomcat logs or code snippets where the problem occurs. With this information no one is able to help you.

Comment: Maybe the file is too big to download

Comment: MMM i think so...theres a solution please???

Comment: Look into your catalina.out if you fine an exception there. For configuration of tomcat look here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: thank you Jens i think this is the problem but is there a way to change the size from tomcar managet oe somthing like that because i dont have web.xml file in my projet

Comment: The Manager should have one:http://tecadmin.net/increase-tomcat-upload-file-size-limit/

Comment: thank you Jens it works now please could answer  this question to be able to marked as the correct answer please

Comment: done. feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the file size of your `war` file. it can not be uploaded, because the max-file-size value is to small. Change it in the `web.xml`of your Manager application

You find the file under /webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml.

There you have to Change in this section:

```
<multipart-config>

      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0<</file-size-threshold>

  </multipart-config>
```